# Pandas.DataFrame.hist() only shows continuous/numerical data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got a dataframe that looks like this:

```
             Pclass     Sex   Age  SibSp  Parch     Fare Embarked  FamilySize  \
PassengerId                                                                     
1                 3    male  22.0      1      0   7.2500        S           2   
2                 1  female  38.0      1      0  71.2833        C           2   
3                 3  female  26.0      0      0   7.9250        S           1   
4                 1  female  35.0      1      0  53.1000        S           2   
5                 3    male  35.0      0      0   8.0500        S           1   

             Alone Title      LName  Survived  
PassengerId                                    
1                0    Mr     Braund       0.0  
2                0   Mrs    Cumings       1.0  
3                1  Miss  Heikkinen       1.0  
4                0   Mrs   Futrelle       1.0  
5                1    Mr      Allen       0.0
```

Using pandas.DataFrame.hist() provides the following printout:

[image]

**This output only displays numerical data, but not the categorical data. The documentation says:**

> This function calls matplotlib.pyplot.hist(), on each series in the DataFrame, resulting in one histogram per column.

I thought this might mean that `matplotlib.pyplot.hist()` might not work on categorical data, so I tried calling it directly on a column containing only categorical data:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.hist(df['Embarked'])
```

And further, I tried calling `.hist()` directly on the sliced dataframe:

```
df['Embarked'].hist()
```

Both of these options yielded perfect results:

[image]

I can think of at least one workaround to fix this, but before I embark on a cumbersome journey, is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The code did what you told it to do. To plot a histogram on a datatframe. When you embarked on a pandas series, it also did what you told it to do. Histograms help you visualise the frequency distribution on a set of continuous data. Please review [pd.df.hist](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html). In pandas, it is applied to a series if you want a single plot. Series is a one-dimensional labeled array capable of holding data of any type (integer, string, float, python objects, etc.). To plot a histogram on categorical data, you must make the series continuous by chaining an appropriate pandas function. I would advice you familiarize yourself with the differences between a [pd.dataframe and pd.series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/dsintro.html)

Comment: Then this statement in the docs is not true "This function calls matplotlib.pyplot.hist(), on each series in the DataFrame, resulting in one histogram per column."

If it actually did that, it would create a plot for each column. In fact, as I stated, I proved that by doing so manually. I called matplotlib.pyplot.hist() directly on Series containing categorical data, and it functioned as mentioned. 

You can bandy about the differences between a barplot and a histogram, but this does not answer the question, nor address the inconsistency within the documentation.